# How to populate the value of a Text Box based on the value in a Combo Box in a html page

Tags: javascript, html

HTML web page:

I have a combo box which is a look up type. I have a selected a look up value from a table.
In the same html page i have two more read only text box which has to store the corresponding values of the look up value.

example : the look up value is name of the person, then the following read only text boxes have to store the phone number and location of the person.

These all values will be stored in the database.

if i change the value in the look up ie person then the phone number and location text boxes have to update automatically.

Comment: please, provide source. You can share it on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax request on change of Combo box.
And send send person ID to server, get location and phone number.
And set those data to read only text boxes.

OR

When you are binding data to combo box, you can set location and phone number in value field with some separator.

Example: value='1^USA^98534869'
Here 1 is person ID, USA is location, 98534869 is phone number separated by ^ symbol.

On change of combo box, get the value and split using separator(^).
And assign that value in read only text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript array and then populate the read only text boxes by fetching the value from the array corresponding to the person ID.

Something like this

```
var details = new Array();
details['person_id'] = new Array();
details['person_id']['name']="name";
details['person_id']['phone_number']="phone_number";
details['person_id']['location']="location";
```